# The definition of 'word-for-word translation'

Tags: translation

Could I have the accurate definition for "word-for-word" translation?

Comment: That is a literal translation, one that renders idioms and language idiosyncrasies verbatim in the destination language. It's usually a very poor sort of translation. Consider how "I'm as corny as Kansas in August" might be rendered literally in another language. It would be almost entirely incomprehensible.

Comment: I don't disagree with Robusto, and yet a scholarly interlinear word-for-word translation, with idioms rendered verbatim rather than in an appropriate counterpart in the target language, but with notes and additional apparatus to explain them, along with word-order differences and related things, can be quite useful and "a good translation" in its own way. Different kinds of translation serve different purposes.

Comment: @TRomano: I don't disagree with you either, but I think we're talking about two ends of the same horse. What you describe sounds to me like an annotated translation, which is what the translator's notes about word and idiom choice are all about.

Comment: So,would it be fair to say that a "word for word" translation is "a rendering of a statement (or a text) from one language into another, with the intention of highlighting features of the original that an idiomatic translation would miss"?

Comment: I don't think intent is implied. "Word for word" means different things to different people in different circumstances. Isn't that ironic?

Comment: The word-for-word translation is the starting point for any translation. As Robusto says, its bad because idioms in the original language are opaque, and the language and word order will be poor for the target language. For example, in Latin the verbs will be at the end.  The next step is to adapt word order, perhaps adapt idioms in the parent language to equivalents in the new, and then adapt the whole to give the same 'sense' to the reader that the original gave the original reader.